# React - Run function if property of an object passed as a prop has changed

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to run a function after a component has updated but only if a property of that object (as a prop!) has changed?

Original object:

```
const employees = {
   employee1: {
      name: "John",
      age: "24"
   },
   employee2: {
      name: "Jane",
      age: "20"
   }
}
```

Updated object (note, John's age has changed):

```
const employees = {
   employee1: {
      name: "John",
      age: "25"
   },
   employee2: {
      name: "Jane",
      age: "20"
   }
}
```

Inside child component getting employees as a prop:

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      const {employees} = this.props;

      if (nextProps.employees !== employees) {
         // Run function...
      }
   }
```

Comment: Use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) callback hook..It has access to `(prevProps, prevState, ..)`

Comment: Can you compare objects in that function? Would a simple comparison like I have in the code above work? `nextProps.employees !== employees`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) callback hook. It has access to `(prevProps, prevState, ..)`.

For equality test I would use [`_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual) method as it performs a deep comparison between two values to determine if they are equivalent.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const {
    employees
  } = this.props;

  if (!_.isEqual(prevProps.employees, employees)) {
    // Run function...
  }
}
```

Note: Look `componentDidUpdate` method is called after the `render()` is executed. So in case you want to dismiss the rendering of the component based on props validation, then [`shouldcomponentupdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) will be correct choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this looks good but it's not working for me. prevProps.employees & employee are always the same... updated with the new props. `prevProps.employees` has always got the new prop, not the previous one.

Comment: @PaulRedmond See this example.. https://codesandbox.io/s/nrq05785lj we have access to current and previous props.

Comment: This is what's happening to me: https://codesandbox.io/s/zwry2o1ow3
From the first click of the button, the 2 values are the new value.

Comment: @PaulRedmond Got it.. it is due to the mutating the same object... Do like me..  this line `employees[0].age = 25;` is mutating the old object.. so create new object every time. This is most important in react. Check https://codesandbox.io/s/yq7452v28j

Comment: I thought creating a copy of the state by assigning it to a new variable was enough, apparently not! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178944/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-paul-redmond).